# How to determine and correct the source of a WHEA-Logger error?

Tags: windows-10, bsod, whea-logger

Over the last few days, my computer has been unwell. I've narrowed the problem down to my HDD, which, at 9 years old, is finally kicking the bucket. After pulling the data off and removing it, the system is much healthier. However, there is still a concerning error in the event viewer that shows up occasionally:

[image]

Following along [with this Microsoft troubleshooting topic](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/numerous-whea-logger-event-id-17-events/38543332-e4fd-4441-b663-98b2030ca43c), I have been looking through the Device Manager to locate this PCI Express Root Port. I did find it, but the hardware ID does not match:

[image]

The Event Viewer error is pointing to **PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_A110&SUBSYS_50011458&REV_F1**, but the only PCI Express Root Port I have in the Device Manager has a hardware ID of **PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1901&SUBSYS_50001458&REV_07**. The siblings Property for this device does contain the ***REV_F1** ID, though it is listed multiple times with additional characters afterwards, so I'm not sure if it's the right thing.

Earlier last week, the WHEA-Logger errors logged just over 12,000 times, leading to an eventual blue screen that crashed so badly, there was no bsod dump file for me to look at. I am assuming this was due to the HDD also failing simultaneously. Since that crash, the WHEA-Logger was silent for a few days before logging 3 times today.

How can I determine what the true source of this WHEA-Logger error is, and how can I correct it?

**EDIT**

I have discovered the source of the errors:

In Powershell:

1. run `pnputil /enum-devices /class System`

this lists all devices within the System class, where the PCI Express Root Port is

2. Search the list for the referenced ***REV_F1** device in the `Instance ID` field

The device appears to be my `Intel(R) 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #13`, although the hardware ID is not exactly matching, as there are additional characters after each instance of the Intel chipset. It applies to all of the following devices:

[image]

#### **The question still remains... how can I fix this error? Should I attempt to update the drivers, Windows updates, etc?**

Comment: This device is the [100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1](https://devicehunt.com/view/type/pci/vendor/8086/device/A110). The problem device is most likely plugged into your first PCIe slot.

Comment: How do you know that it's pointing to port 1? I can't figure this part out yet.

Comment: From "PCI Express Root **Port #1**".

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. Per the OP, the referenced REV_F1 hardware ID is applied to each of those PCI Express ports. Regardless, I do not have anything plugged into PCIe 1. I have a an m.2 SSD plugged into my secondary port (M2A_32G), and a GTX 1070 plugged into the first PCIEX16 slot. Otherwise, there are two Samsung SSDs plugged in with traditional SATA power/data cables.

Comment: There's only one with "DEV_A110". To identify, try in PowerShell the command `(gwmi Win32_Bus -Filter 'DeviceID like "PCI%"').GetRelated('Win32_PnPEntity').GetDeviceProperties('DEVPKEY_Device_LocationInfo').deviceProperties | ft data,DeviceID`. I took it from [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/103629/windows-equivalent-for-lspci).

Comment: Aha i see, thanks for clarifying! You can definitely post your notes as an answer, as it did help me identify the source of the WHEA-Logger error. I'm still stumped on how a PCIe slot without something plugged into it can throw errors, but I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This PCI device with the ID of "VEN_8086&DEV_A110" is the
[100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1](https://devicehunt.com/view/type/pci/vendor/8086/device/A110).

The problem device is most likely plugged into your first PCIe slot
(Root Port #1).
If nothing is plugged into it, then there might be a problem with the
motherboard.

To identify the devices plugged into PCIe ports, run in PowerShell
the command:

```
(gwmi Win32_Bus -Filter 'DeviceID like "PCI%"').GetRelated('Win32_PnPEntity').GetDeviceProperties('DEVPKEY_Device_LocationInfo').deviceProperties | ft data,DeviceID
```

More methods can be found in the post
[Windows Equivalent for lspci?](https://serverfault.com/questions/103629/windows-equivalent-for-lspci)

Comment: Correct the command line `DeviceID.` -> `DeviceID` at the end.

Comment: @huang: Thanks (copy-paste error),